# Can anybody explain "sending your money off to do the heavy lifting" for me, please?

Tags: terminology, financial-advisor

> Sean Gould, a wealth strategist with Waddell and Associates and a
>   certified financial planner, explains that before sending your money
>   off to do the heavy lifting, you'll want to have an emergency savings
>   account of about six months of living expenses stored in cash.

source: http://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-make-your-money-work-for-you-2016-11/#-8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a spin on the phrase "making your money work for you".

> before sending your money off to do the heavy lifting, you'll want to
>   have an emergency savings account of about six months of living
>   expenses stored in cash.

Basically, he is saying *before you start to invest* make sure you have sufficient emergency savings.

Answer (score 3):

"Sending your money off to do the heavy lifting" is just a stylish way to say "investing".

He is saying hold back 6 months of living expenses and *don't* invest it.   Keep it in cash or some cash-like investment (genuinely safe and liquid).

It's good basic solid advice you'll also get from Dave Ramsey, Suze Orman and any financial advisor worth a darn.

While this is good advice, that does not mean *all* of his advice is good.  A classic con-man trick is to tell you three things you know are true, mixed with a lie they want you to believe.  They want you to think "I know 3/4 are true so the fourth probably is too."

Answer (score 0):

Sending your money off to do the heavy lifting is a way of saying that compound returns can do the bulk of your retirement investing work.

Check out the image below, I swiped this from a quick google search so I cannot claim graphic credit. But as you can see the earning potential of your money as you approach retirement is many times higher than your annual contributions.

With the aim of having your money earn interest/returns to pay your annual living expenses, replacing your previous annual income.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpZPN.jpg

I tried to post the image but do not have enough rep.